# API is recieving a GET request when i send a POST?

Tags: php, apache, postman, slim

I developed my RESTful API using PHP with slim and tested it on my local machine sending requests with Postman. I then deployed the API to a remote server (linode with LAMP).

My problem is when i send the exact same "POST" message to the new host address i get an error message saying "METHOD NOT ALLOWED". It looks like Postman is sending a "GET" request (But probably not since it is the exact same request i just changed the address). Somehow my API is receiving a "GET" request any suggestions as to how this could be possible would be great.

The body of the request is raw XML and the header reflects that.

Comment: Could you give the request path that you use postman and routes that related to it?

Comment: Have you looked at postman console to see what the request looks like?

Comment: hey thanks both for the response. It turned out i was sending the post with a http url and since the site was set up for https there was an automatic redirect (utilizing get). I need to understand the http protocol better....